TypeInitializationException/NullReferenceException calling C# dll func from pythonnet. Call stack shows the exception is in ProductPaths.cs file in C#
[![pythonC#Exceptions][1]][1]I am calling the C# dll from python and then loading the python v3.11 module in National Instruments Test Stand. I am getting the same exceptions in python and in Test Stand. When I run the program in C# only there isn't a problem, it works the way it should
I attached a screenshot to the error in python.
I am not sure what to try to find what is causing the problem. I would appreciate any suggestions on what it could be. I know that python strings are UTF-8 and C# is UTF-16 but I tried reading a C# string in Python and it worked. I'm not sure if it creates a problem though in the path.combine function.
Thanks
// File:
//    NgpvPaths.cs
// Purpose:
//    This module methods for accessing application paths to data
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace NGPV.Common.AppConfig
{
// --------------------------------------------------------------------    // <summary>
//     This class provides static routines for accessing generic application paths.
    // </summary>
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    public class ProductPaths
    {
        /// -----------------------------------------------------------     /// <summary>
        ///     Class constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// ----------------------------------------------------------- 
 static ProductPaths()
 {           
    ReleaseNumber = GetReleaseNumber();
    ProgramExecutableFolder = ExpandPathMacros("{ExecutableFolder}");
    SetupFolders();
 }

 public static string ReleaseNumber { get; }
 public static string ProgramDataFolder { get; private set; }
 public static string ProgramExecutableFolder { get; private set; }

 public static string ProgramExecutableDataFolder => 
Path.Combine(ProgramExecutableFolder, _dataFolder);
        public static string ProgramExecutableDataJsonFilesFolder => Path.Combine(ProgramExecutableFolder, _dataJsonFiles);
        public static string TonesFolder => Path.Combine(ProgramExecutableDataFolder, "Tones");
        public static string EnglishFolder => Path.Combine(ProgramExecutableDataFolder, "English");
        public static string DefaultVoiceFolder => Path.Combine(EnglishFolder, _voiceFolder);
        public static string VoiceSubfolderName => _voiceFolder;
        
public static string NgpvRoot => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _ngpvRootFolder);
public static string DataPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _dataFolder);
public static string DoctorsPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _doctorsFolder);
public static string SystemPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _systemFolder);
public static string VoImagesFolder => Path.Combine(DataPath, "Vo Images");
public static string AnimationsFolder => Path.Combine(DataPath, "Animations");
public static string InstalledLanguagesFolder => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, "Locale");
public static string LanguagePackFolder => Path.Combine(_removeableMediaRootFolder, "Language Packs", ReleaseNumber);
public static string ConfigPath =>    Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _configFolder);
public static string CertificatePath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _certificateFolder);
public static string LogPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _logFolder); //TODO rename to AuxiliaryLogPath
public static string EventLogPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _eventLogFolder);
public static string LogArchivePath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _logArchiveFolder);
public static string LogArchivePath_Event => Path.Combine(LogArchivePath, _eventLogFolder);
public static string LogArchivePath_Auxiliary => Path.Combine(LogArchivePath, _logFolder);
public static string CaseLogsPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _caseLogsFolder);
public static string DynamicViewsPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, (string)Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName), "DynamicViews");
public static string ServiceViewsPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, (string)Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName), "ServiceViews");

#warning FW - Need to dynamically set WindowsLogPath instead of hardcoding. Why can't it be part of ProgramData?
public static string WindowsLogPath => @"D:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs";

public static string DiagDataPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _eventLogFolder);
public static string ServiceMaintPath => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, "ServiceMaintenance");
public static string UvcsExportBaseFolder => Path.Combine(_removeableMediaRootFolder, "Export");
public static string UvcsImportBaseFolder { get => _removeableMediaRootFolder; }
// The following propeties needs to be validated.
public static string ToolsFolder => Path.Combine(ProgramDataFolder, _toolsFolder);

// --------------------------------------------------------------------       /// <summary>
        ///     This routine sets the static property ProgramDataFolder.
        /// </summary>
        /// -----------------------------------------------------------
public static void EstablishProgramDataFolder(string programDataFolder, string releaseNumber = "")
        {
ProgramDataFolder = ExpandPathMacros(programDataFolder, releaseNumber);
        }
// --------------------------------------------------------------------      // <summary>
//     Expands the path macros.
// </summary>
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
public static string ExpandPathMacros(string filePath, string releaseNumber = "")
        {            
       filePath = filePath.Replace("{ExecutableFolder}",
                Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName));
filePath = filePath.Replace("{ProgramFiles}",
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles));
            filePath = filePath.Replace("{ProgramData}",
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(_progDataEnvVariable) ??
                    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData));

            filePath = filePath.Replace("{ReleaseNumber}", releaseNumber);
            return filePath;
        }

        private static void CreateFolders(string folder)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                _ = Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            }
        }

        public static void SetupFolders()
        {
            bool isConsole = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(_progDataEnvVariable) != null);
            string releaseFolder = isConsole ? "" : "\\{ReleaseNumber}";    // Do not include REL_xxxx folder on console
            string programDataPath = "{ProgramData}\\Alcon\\NGPV" + releaseFolder;

            ProgramDataFolder = ExpandPathMacros(programDataPath, ReleaseNumber);
            // Create all folders if they do not exist
            CreateFolders(ProgramDataFolder);
            CreateFolders(DoctorsPath);
            CreateFolders(SystemPath);
            CreateFolders(ConfigPath);
            CreateFolders(DataPath);
            CreateFolders(LogPath);
            CreateFolders(DiagDataPath);
            CreateFolders(ToolsFolder);
            CreateFolders(EventLogPath);
            CreateFolders(LogArchivePath);
            CreateFolders(LogArchivePath_Event);
            CreateFolders(LogArchivePath_Auxiliary);
        }
        
        private static string GetReleaseNumber()
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
            return "REL_" + fileVersionInfo.ProductMajorPart.ToString("00") + "." + fileVersionInfo.ProductMinorPart.ToString("00");
        }

        /// -----------------------------------------------------------
        /// Constants
        /// -----------------------------------------------------------
private const string _progDataEnvVariable       = @"AlconProgramData";
private const string _ngpvRootFolder            = @"Alcon\NGPV";
private const string _removeableMediaRootFolder = @"Alcon\UVCS";
private const string _configFolder              = "Configurations";
private const string _certificateFolder         = "Certificates";
private const string _dataFolder                = "Data";
private const string _dataJsonFiles             = "DataJsonFiles";
private const string _doctorsFolder             = @"Doctors\";
private const string _systemFolder              = @"System\";
private const string _toolsFolder               = "Tools";
private const string _logFolder                 = "AuxiliaryLogs";
private const string _eventLogFolder            = "EventLogs";
private const string _logArchiveFolder          = "_LogArchive";
private const string _caseLogsFolder            = "CaseLogs";
private const string _voiceFolder               = "Audio";
    }
}

import pythonnet
import os
pythonnet.load("coreclr")
import clr
import sys
               
#USING PYTHONNET LIBRARY
class CSharpAsmblyRefs: 
      
    releaseNum = ""
   
   def __init__(self):
        assembly_Config_path = (r"C:\\source\\repos\\Host\\Tools\\TestFramework.Test\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\net6.0-windows\\")
        assembly_CSharpdll_path = (r"C:\\python311\\modules\\python_env2\\")
        sys.path.append(assembly_CSharpdll_path)        
        
        clr.AddReference("ScriptingClientLib")
        clr.AddReference("NGPV.Common.ProtoDefinition")
        clr.AddReference("NGPV.Common.RPC")
        clr.AddReference("NGPV.Common.TraceListener")
        clr.AddReference("NGPV.Common.UIBase")
        clr.AddReference("ScriptingCommander")
        clr.AddReference("Diag")
        clr.AddReference("NGPV.Common.AppConfig")
        
        from ScriptingClientLib import ScriptingClient
        
        clr.AddReference("NGPV.Common.AppConfig")        
        from NGPV.Common.AppConfig import ProductPaths

        sys.path.append(assembly_Config_path)
        clr.AddReference("System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager")
        from System.Configuration import ConfigurationManager
                  
        scrptClient = ScriptingClient()
        scrptClient.RunAsync("Initialize.csx")

I am now getting these errors in python when I exclude the call to the static GetRealeaseNumber function in the C# ProductPaths.cs constructor: It looks like now it's looking for Grpc.core for version 2.0.0. I only have v2.42.0 and v2.46.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Modules\python_env2\CSharpdll_pythonnet_Class.py", line 82, in <module>
    sc = CSharpAsmblyRefs()
  File "C:\Python311\Modules\python_env2\CSharpdll_pythonnet_Class.py", line 51, in __init__
    scrptClient.RunAsync("Initialize.csx")
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Grpc.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Grpc.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad'
   at NGPV.Common.Diag.ScriptingCommander..ctor(String host, Int32 port)
   at ScriptingClientLib.ScriptPackageViewModel..ctor()
   at ScriptingClientLib.ScriptPackageViewModel.get_Instance()
   at ScriptingClientLib.ScriptingClient.RunAsync(String csxFileName)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)


The NGPV.Common.AppConfig.ProductPaths class has a static constructor. It throws an exception. See what it tries to do that it cannot do when you start it from Python.

I called the static GetReleaseNumber() method from python and I got a System.NullReferenceException

Why does this function fail from python and not in C#?

Because you call that code from Python in such environment that whatever must happen in the static constructor of NGPV.Common.AppConfig.ProductPaths, fails to happen?

Is there a way to stop this from happening from Python? are Static functions handled different than in C#? Thank you for you help.

Yes, by looking what it's trying to do so that you could figure how to let it do it. Handling of anything in Python has no relation to it.
